# Transposing the datatable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have following controller code that extracts Goals for Sales reps by months. The table that I want to create is first column should contain the list of Sales reps (one in each row), and subsequent columns would have months in first row and the respective goals against each sales rep. To help the visualization, I have inserted a picture of table in Excel

[image]

following is the controller:

```
public List<RevMonthsrep> getRevMonthsrep()
{
 List<RevMonthsrep> accs = new List<RevMonthsrep>();     
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;     
for (User_Stats__c a : [Select Sales_Rep__c, Month_Number__c,Year__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c 
    where ((Month_Number__c = : today.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(today.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthPlus1.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus1.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthPlus2.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthPlus2.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus1.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus1.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus2.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus2.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus3.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus3.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus4.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus4.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus5.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus5.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus6.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus6.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus7.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus7.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus8.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus8.year()))
    OR (Month_Number__c = : monthMinus9.month() AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus9.year()))) 
    and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist
     order by Year__c asc, Month_Number__c asc])
{
    RevMonthsrep opp = new RevMonthsrep((Integer) integer.valueof(a.get('Month_Number__c')),
                                              (String)a.get('Sales_Rep__c'),
                                              (Double)a.get('Rental_Revenue_Goal__c'));    
    accs.add(opp);
}

 return accs;

}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:pageblock >
  <apex:dataTable value="{!SalesReps2}" var="test" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F5FFFA">
    <apex:column headerValue="Sales Rep" value="{!test.Sales_Rep__c}">
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Month" value="{!test.Month_Number__c}">
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Goal" value="{!test.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c}">
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Let me know if additional code is also required. 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: So, whats your question ?

Comment: I want to create this table in VisualForce and I have no idea how.

Comment: Have you already tried something ?

Comment: What I have tried is to create a normal datatable. I have (updated the code with it). But I dont know how can I get the months in column.

Comment: Is SalesReps2=getRevMonthsrep() somewhere in your code, what are you getting on your VF page right now / what's not happening ? You appear to be pretty close.

Comment: Yeah that is correct. Sorry, in the VF page it is RevMonthsrep instead of SalesRep2